# Ignore Windows related questions?

Tags: support, tags

I've been active on Android Enthusiasts mostly so far and answer more than ask questions there. I guess it'll be the same over here so here's my question:

I'm not a huge Windows expert and thus would like to 'ignore' Windows/Microsoft related questions if possible.

How can I do this besides adding all relevant tags to my ignore list (which I did for some already)?

Comment: You already found the solution.

Comment: Well, I anticipated that. :-) So I'd need to update my ignore list when new tags emerge, right?

Comment: although, as one of the most popular tags, there is certainly ample material to edit, etc. even if you don't answer them.  :)

Comment: Of course. They're just greyed out.

Comment: Ah, I've never ignored a tag, and wasn't sure how that goes after the fact.  Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only option is to make use of the ignore list. Note that it's possible to use wildcards you don't have to add every variant of a tag.

[image]